# java accelerated graphics

Tags: java, graphics, hardware-acceleration

I want to try making 2d games in java using the Graphics2d class. I keep getting images which flicker. I did a bit of research and found out that I have to use accelerated graphics for faster frame rates. How do I do this?

I need to know how to draw images extremely fast and how to stop my screen from flickering.

Beyond examples, I'd appreciate any references to tutorials for basic accelerated graphics as well. For instance, I found [this one](http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d.html) useful, but I want to learn the basics.

Comment: Simple. Don't use Graphics2D. Use a 2d library such as Slick2d. Its much cleaner, easier, and suited to the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Flicker isn't caused by the frame rate, but by lack of double buffering. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html) for more information on the subject.

For hardware acceleration, you need to use the [VolatileImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html) class. Read [this](http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=16840&tstart=0) for description with code samples.